# Design a data structure for Optimum result for retrieving data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, hashtable

Recently i saw this question in one of the book i was referring to for technical interviews. Question was something like this -

You are given data about students who had taken some subjects. 
You need to make a data structure such that if I query for no of students in a subject or no of subjects a student has taken, the complexity should be less.

So for example there are students P1 who was taken S1, S2 and S3 subjects - student P2 has taken S1, S4 subjects. When i query for subjects taken by P1 - answer should be S1,S2,S3
and when i ask question who has taken S1 - answer should be P1 & P2

So far what i have tried...

Initially i started solving the problem using a combination of HashMap and LinkedList.
But at most what i have got retrieval is O(1) and O(N) time with O(N) space. Do you think i can do this better? I also thought of using BST but that didn't quite work.

Looking forward to have some interesting responses!!

Answer (score 1):

A combination of this should work:

- HashMap of student to list of subjects
- HashMap of subject to list of students

This allows for expected `O(1)` retrieval of either the list of subjects a student is taking, or the list of students that's taking a subject (presumably the list structure will store a count to allow `O(1)` retrieval of the number of elements).

The space complexity is `O(n)`.

If you only want the counts, you could consider replacing the "list of students" (and perhaps even "list of subjects") with simply a count.

If you want to support removal or existence checks, "list of subjects" or "list of students" is not going to be particularly efficient. To do so efficiently, you could replace those lists with HashSets.

Comment: Can we do better than this in terms of memory usage here?